# WordPress heading 6 font become bold + another issue

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am writing an article on WordPress.

when i choose heading 6 font size "which is the smallest font i have those issues:

1: the font become Bold

2: when i use bullet-list the spacing between the lines is too big

i want to have regular font and normal spacing and the edit must be at style.css file

```
    li > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 24px;
}
li > ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

ignore this link.
http://www.abdorefky.com/heading-6-issue/

Comment: mmm,, then how to change it

Comment: and why people keep giving me bad reputation . 
very clear problem + example also !!!!

Comment: about the link it's an addition, and the post the is same without it

Comment: read the post without the link you will understand every thing :)

Comment: i wont do that in the future since people are sensitive to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the `h6` inside an `li` to be bold (which it is by default), you have to override it.

```
li h6 {
   font-weight:normal;
}
```

If you want ALL `h6` not to be bold.

```
h6 {
   font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: i want to override it on all places to be normal

Comment: Great, now what about the li spacing ?

Comment: For that you need to show us the full code that affects it...as is **required** by Stack Overflow. A link to your demo page is not enough.

Comment: sure, can i send the whole 1400 style.css lines ?

Comment: i will search about li

Comment: We only need a **minimal demo**...just enough to show the problem.

Comment: h6 {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.2782608695;
    font-weight: normal;
     }

Comment: How would I know? Once you recreate the problem in a Stack Snippet other people can help you.

Comment: i don't know what part of the code is causing this problem . 
when i press f12 and follow the lines i can see the bullet-list include a yellow space between the lines.... But with the other font size it doesn't include that yellow space in bullet-list .